# Getting message Specific to Tenant Id

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus

Currently Topic receives all message irrespective to the **TenantId**

But My requirement is that only message belongs a particular **TenantId** should be received at the receiver end.

**Example:**

Currently It is happening as below

> Message 1 Tenant 1 => Receiver
>   Message 2 Tenant 2 => Receiver

But now it should behave as below:

> Message 1 Tenant 1 => Receiver(Tenant1)
>   Message 2 Tenant 2 => Receiver(Tenant2)

**Whether this can be implemented by PartitionKeyId?**

Any suggestion please? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a rule on each subscriber on the topic where the rule will decide if a message should be sent to the subscribers queue or not.

The rules can't be manually added in the azure portal but you can add them via below script based on the `Microsoft.ServiceBus` nuget package

```
var topicName = "yourTopicName";
var serviceBusConnectionString = "yourServiceBusManageRule";
var nameSpaceMgr = NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString(serviceBusConnectionString);
var messagingFactory = MessagingFactory.CreateFromConnectionString(serviceBusConnectionString);
var tenants = new List<string>{ "Tenant1", "Tenant2" };

foreach (var tenant in tenants)
{
    var subscriptionClient = messagingFactory.CreateSubscriptionClient(topicName, tenant);
    var subscriberFilter = new SqlFilter($"Tenant = '{tenant}'");
    var subscriberRuleName = "TenantRule";
    var subscriberRule = new RuleDescription(subscriberRuleName, subscriberFilter);

    var defaultRule = "$Default";
    if (nameSpaceMgr.GetRules(topicName, tenant).Any(r=> r.Name == defaultRule))
    {
        subscriptionClient.RemoveRule(defaultRule);
    }

    if (nameSpaceMgr.GetRules(topicName, tenant).Any(r => r.Name == subscriberRuleName))
    {
        subscriptionClient.RemoveRule(subscriberRuleName);
    }
    subscriptionClient.AddRule(subscriberRule);
}
```

Then when sending a BrokeredMessage (`Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging` package) on the topic, define the Tenant property with the current tenant

```
var msg = new BrokeredMessage(e);
msg.Properties.Add("Tenant", "Tenant1");
```

Comment: I strongly recommend trying out the Service Bus Explorer. That allows you to inspect the rules and add new ones using a GUI tool instead https://github.com/paolosalvatori/ServiceBusExplorer

Comment: @Svend Nice! Have used it but didn't know you could add rules from there

Comment: @MarcusHöglund  can I use this approach for existing Topic/Subscription as well?

Comment: @MarirajR yes, this solution is for existing topic and subscription